# Validation for AutoComplete in Kendo Batch editing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using **kendo `Grid` batch editing** in which i have used `AutoComplete` through Editortemplate which is as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
          .Name("AccountTransactionItemHead")
          .DataTextField("Value_AccountTransactionItemHead")
          //.DataValueField("HeaderID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
          .Filter("contains")

          //.AutoBind(true)
          .Events(events => events.Select("HeadComboSelect"))
          .MinLength(3)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetHeadForHeadGrid", "Cashbox");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
)
```

Now i want the validation for this if I don't select any value in this and if i move to second column it must validate for this field that "please select the AutoComplete".
My `Grid` and ViewModel is as follows:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter Head")]
        public string AccountTransactionItemHead { get; set; }
        public int lkpQualifier { get; set; }
        public string lkpQualifierType { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Description")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please Use letters only")]
        public string AccountTransactionItemDescription { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Currency")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please Use letters only")]
        public string AccountTransactionItemCurrency { get; set; }  

 columns.Bound(p => p.AccountTransactionItemHead).Title("Head").EditorTemplateName("HeadAutoComplete").ClientTemplate("#=AccountTransactionItemHead#").Width(120);
    columns.Bound(p => p.AccountTransactionItemQualifier).Title("Trade Type").EditorTemplateName("AccountTransactionItemTradeDropDown").ClientTemplate("#=AccountTransactionItemQualifier#" + "<input type='hidden' class='lkpQualifierType' value='#=data.AccountTransactionItemQualifier#' />").Width(100);
    columns.Bound(p => p.TestHeader).ClientTemplate("#=TestHeader# <input type='hidden' class='AccountTransactionHeaderID' value='#=TestHeader#' />").Hidden(true);
    columns.Bound(p => p.AccountTransactionItemDescription).Title("Description").Width(130).ClientTemplate("#= AccountTransactionItemDescription#" + "<input type='hidden' class='AccountTransactionItemDescription'  value='#=data.AccountTransactionItemDescription#' />");
    columns.Bound(p => p.AccountTransactionItemCurrency).Width(80).Title("Currency").EditorTemplateName("CurrencyAutoComplete").ClientTemplate("#= AccountTransactionItemCurrency#" + "<input type='hidden' class='AccountTransactionItemCurrency'  value='#=data.AccountTransactionItemCurrency#' />");
    columns.Bound(p => p.AmtTransact).Width(100).Title("Amt Trans").ClientTemplate("#= AmtTransact#" + "<input type='hidden' class='AmtTransact'  value='#=data.AmtTransact#' />");
```

I need the Validation for First Column that is `AccountTransactionItemHead`.

Comment: So is it showing `Please Enter Head` now ?

Comment: no..right now no validation on this

Comment: No message as I am using EditorTemplate but getting message for others  ...except the fields that are using EditorTemplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using kendo validator..

```
1.//Grid Custom Validation            
                  $("#GridName").kendoValidator({
                 rules: {
                     // custom rules
                     custom: function (input, params) {

                         if (input.is("[name=AccountTransactionItemHead]")) {

                             //If the input is AccountTransactionItemHead 
                            var autoComplete= input.val()
                             //check value is null or empty
                             if(autoComplete==null || autoComplete=="")
                              retrun false; //trigger validation

                         }

                         //check for the rule attribute
                         return true;
                     }
                 },
                 messages: {
                     custom: function (input) {
                         // return the message text
                         return "please select the AutoComplete!";
                     }
                 }
             })
```

1. Another Grid Validation

   ```
    $("#GridName").kendoValidator({
                    rules: {

                        AccountTransactionItemHead: {
                              required: true,
                 productnamevalidation: function (input) {
                                           if (input.is(" [name='AccountTransactionItemHead']") && input.val() == ""){return false; //tigger validation show message }
                        //else valition passed value is not null or empty
                    return true;         
                            }//end of function                                
                        }// end of rules;
                    },
                    messages: {
                        productnamevalidation: function (input) {
                            // return the message text
                            return "please select the AutoComplete!";
                        }
                    }
                })
   ```
2. answer using Kenod.Ui.Validator

   ```
    //Add validation on Service rate Grid       

    (function ($, kendo) {

           $.extend(true, kendo.ui.validator, {
               rules: {
                   greaterdate: function (input) {
                       if (input.is("[data-val-greaterdate]") && input.val() != "") {
                           var date = kendo.parseDate(input.val()),
                               earlierDate = kendo.parseDate($("[name='" + input.attr("data-val-greaterdate-earlierdate") + "']").val());
                           return !date || !earlierDate || earlierDate.getTime() < date.getTime();
                       }

                       return true;
                   }

                   // custom rules
                   taskdate: function (input, params) {

                       if (input.is("[name=WorkOrderDetailsDate]")) {

                           //If the input is StartDate or EndDate
                           var container = $(input).closest("tr");
                           var tempTask = container.find("input[name=WorkOrderDetailsDate]").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
                           var tempWork = $("#workOrder_EstStartDate").val();

                           var workDate = kendo.parseDate(tempWork);
                           var taskDate = kendo.parseDate(tempTask);
                           if (taskDate < workDate) {
                               return false;
                           }
                       }

                       //check for the rule attribute
                       return true;
                   }

               }, //end of rule                       
               messages: {
                   greaterdate: function (input) {
                       return input.attr("data-val-greaterdate");
                   },                        
                   taskdate: function (input) {
                       return "Task date must be after work date!";
                   },
               }
           });
       })(jQuery, kendo);
   ```

Comment: Its not working I just want to know when this event must fire?as it is not firing up when i checked in console..

Comment: if the value of auto complete is null or empty then it will return false causing message to show.. please select auto complete..

Comment: have a look at telerik validation link as well. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-custom-validation.html

Comment: updated again...us input.val() instead on container ....as container is used to pick closest tr.... as var container = $(input).closest("tr");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49930/discussion-between-shaz-and-santyessac)

Comment: in that case if it disappears.. use kendo.ui.validtor same logic little syntex changed. have look at my updated version of the answer..

Comment: third should works for you mate...and please accept the answer if you it resolved your issue..thanx

Comment: I am getting a cursor on  return "please select the AutoComplete!"; in debug mode but the error template showing the message is not appearing